# Vue 2 hook ready

Tags: vuejs2

Vue 2, Is there a lifecycle hook that actually refers to "finished rendering"? I want to put a loading screen when entering a page and it fades away and show the page content once Vue is finished loading everything, but I have tried most of the lifecycle hook but not working. Here is something I would try to do if `updated` refers to "finished rendering":

```
updated(){
  this.loaded()
},
methods:{
  loaded(){
    var vm = this;
    this.loading = false;
  }
}
```

If there is not such a lifecycle hook, what would you suggest me to do instead? Thanks

Answer (score 8):

Probably the method you're looking for is `mounted()`, this is fired when the vue component is ready. You can check the Vue life-cycle documentation [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Instance-Lifecycle-Hooks)

so probably your Vue instance would look something like this:

```js
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    /*
     * When the instance is loaded up
     */
    mounted: function () {
        this.loaded()
    },
    methods: {
        loaded: function () {
            var vm = this
            this.loading = false
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. This makes this.loading = false at the start of page loading. So the loading icon does not even show in this case.... I want this icon to be gone upon all other codes finished loading.

Answer (score 2):

To make sure that all child components have also been mounted, use `vm.$nextTick` - much cleaner than a setTimeout:

```
mounted: function () {
  this.$nextTick(function () {
    // Code that will run only after the
    // entire view has been rendered
  })
}
```

Source: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Options-Lifecycle-Hooks

Comment: Also much more reliable and time efficient. `setTimeout` is kind of a last resort. It's like a "I have no idea what i'm waiting for  exactly but the deadline is not waiting for me, that's for sure" kind of solution.

Comment: does not work. at least in vue 3

Answer (score 0):

As I cannot find that there is a specific lifecycle hook or other Vue-specified method to hook the point where everything is finished rendering, I used the basic js code as well as estimation of time needed for loading all the things with codes as following:

```
mounted(){
  this.loaded()
},
methods:{
  loaded(){
    var vm = this;
    setTimeout(function(){
      vm.loading = false
    }, 3000);
  }
}
```

Hope there will be someone who is strong at Vue and provide a new answer to hook it more accurately.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, your answer to your question is not what you have asked originally, the Vue instance is rendered in less than a second and it's not possible to use any hooks only to create userfriendly loader.
The case in using `setTimeout` function is the only solution for this. But the component is ready in DOM a way earlier than 3 seconds.

The best approach for this purpose is to use loader component, where you will have `setTimeout` in `created` hook and after this time it will emit event to the parent.
So inside app you need only to import the loader component itself and when the event fires, change internal boolean data property to render another component [v-if](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html)